# Syntax to query for optional relationships in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Graph Database?

Tags: sparql, graph-databases, sql-server-2017, sql-graph, sql-server-2017-graph

I want to select optional relationships in [sql-server-2017-graph](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017-graph).  Similar to `optional` in [sparql](/questions/tagged/sparql) e.g.:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name ?mbox
WHERE  { ?x foaf:name  ?name .
     OPTIONAL { ?x  foaf:mbox  ?mbox }
   }
```

from https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rq23/#OptionalMatching.

And similar to [`LEFT JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) in normal [sql](/questions/tagged/sql); e.g.:

```
SELECT name, mbox
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN PersonMailBoxLink ON Persons.$node_id = PersonMailBoxLink.$from_id
LEFT JOIN MailBoxes ON PersonMailBoxLink.$to_id = MailBoxes.$node_id
```

Is there an easier way via [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph)?

The [documentation of `MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) describes no 'optional' construct and the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph#remarks) state:

> `OR` and `NOT` operators are not supported in the `MATCH` pattern. `MATCH` can be combined with other expressions using `AND` in the `WHERE` clause. However, combining it with other expressions using `OR` or `NOT` is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`LEFT JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) with [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph).  Put the optional [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) in a separate nested query.  Put the optional subquery in a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql)-clause.

The query is a bit cumbersome.  The main [graph search pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph#syntax) and the optional graph search pattern need separate [`Node`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph)-tables to use the graph `MATCH`-syntax.  A third instance of the `Node`-table is needed to `LEFT JOIN` the optional clause on.  This third `Node`-table instance must be separate from the `Node`-table used to `MATCH` the main query part on since using `MATCH` requires<sup>1</sup> a [`table_or_view_name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#syntax) and cannot use a [`<joined_table>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#syntax).

The OP example has no main graph search pattern, so there is little benefit from using a nested `JOIN`.  However, this would be the resulting query:

```
SELECT [pLhs].[name],
    [mbox]
FROM [Persons] as [pLhs]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [pRhs].$node_id AS [pRhsNodeId],
        [mbox]
    FROM [Persons] as [pRhs]
        [PersonMailBoxLink],
        [MailBoxes]
    WHERE MATCH ([Persons]-([PersonMailBoxLink])->[MailBoxes])
) AS [optionalGsp] ON [pLhs].$node_id = [optionalGsp].[pRhsNodeId];
```

A more extended example with both a main graph search pattern and an optional graph search pattern give a better demonstration of combing graph `MATCH` with optional `LEFT JOIN`.  The following uses the [SQL Graph Sample Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample); select John's friends and optionally the restaurants that these friends like:

```
SELECT [Person].[Name] as friend,
    [optionalGsp].[resaurantName],
FROM [Person] AS person1,
    [Person] AS person2,
    [friendOf],
    [Person] AS person2Lhs
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT person2Rhs.$node_id AS rhsNodeId,
            [Restaurant].[Name] AS restaurantName
        FROM [Person] AS person2Rhs,
            [likes],
            [Restaurant]
        WHERE MATCH (person2Rhs-(likes)->Restaurant)
    ) AS optionalGsp
WHERE MATCH (person1-(friendOf)->person2)
AND person1.name = 'John'
AND person2.$node_id = person2Lhs.$node_id
```

In the original [sample database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample) every person likes a restaurant, so the is no difference between the complicate query above and `MATCH(person1-(friendOf)->person2-(likes)->Restaurant)`.  However, when you delete Sally liking Ginger and Spice:

```
DELETE FROM likes
WHERE $from_id = (SELECT $node_id FROM Persons WHERE name = 'Sally')
AND $to_id = (SELECT $node_id FROM Restaurants WHERE name = 'Ginger and Spice')
```

The query with the optional `LEFT JOIN` still returns Sally as a friend of `John`.  The results show `NULL` for Sally's restaurant.  `MATCH(person1-(friendOf)->person2-(likes)->Restaurant)` does not show Sally.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[`MATCH` §Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph#arguments) and [Use views and table valued functions as node or edge tables in match clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708948/814206) describe this restriction on the tables that can be used in the `MATCH`-clause.</sub>