# SQL Server GRAPH: Match Query - not declaring all types [NOT POSSIBLE]

Tags: sql-server, neo4j, cypher, sql-server-2017-graph, sql-graph

I'm doing research into SQL Server Graph vs Neo4J for my internship.

- In Neo4J I don't have to declare all types in the (`Cypher`) MATCH query
- In SQL Server, it seems that I have to do so

Examples:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT Restaurant.name
FROM Person, likes, Restaurant
WHERE MATCH (Person-(likes)->Restaurant)
  AND Person.name = 'John';`
```

I want to change Person / Likes / Restaurant to not predefined types

Like in Neo4J:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r]->(m) WHERE n.name = "John"
```

I know that these two queries are not comparable but I'm trying to point out that I would like to use "**r(elation)**" and "**m**" in SQL Server.

It looks close to this SO: [Syntax to query for optional relationships in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Graph Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629625/syntax-to-query-for-optional-relationships-in-microsoft-sql-server-2017-graph-da) but I hope I could do this without joins.

**Edit: CLOSED: This feature is not supported by Microsoft**

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s okay, deleted my previous comment. Tell me please how this is relevant to the issue. If you copy the full query you will find the Microsoft SQL graph page where it's from. I only copied it.

Comment: @marc_s any comment?